# Magento payment method does not show in safari

Tags: php, html, magento, payment

I have multiple payment methods which show fine in Google Chrome, but for some reason one of them does not show up in Safari or IE. It's really weird. Does anyone have any idea what I can check to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Is there code to check?

Comment: @13ruce1337 That's the weird thing -- when I look at the source code, the code for that specific payment method isn't there. It probably has to do with that specific payment method? But it is weird that it works just fine in Google Chrome.

Comment: if it shows up in chrome, but not the others, post the snippet that shows up in chrome.

Comment: @13ruce1337 Sure, <dt>
                            <input id="p_method_idl" value="idl" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="p" class="radio validate-one-required-by-name" checked="checked">
                            <label for="p_method_idl">iDEAL</label>
            </dt>

Comment: is there any css involved? post that and what you've stated above in the question. maybe any JS to. just remember to only post relevant code.

Comment: Try to use other computer or clean safari caches, you can have css files or js stored in browser cache. Or safari can gave you an error feedback by console

Comment: Most probably, the problem must be related to layout. check your templates related to payment methods.